# Magento installed, back-end working but front-end problems

Tags: .htaccess, magento, frontend

I just purchased a Virtual Dedicated Server from godaddy. I just had Magento installed and the back-end is working. I'm able to access the admin panel and everything seems fine. However, on the front end I'm getting problems. When I visit the home page on a web browser it comes up as a blank page. No 404 error. But when I visit "myDomain.com/httpdocs/index.php", the website  pops up and mostly everything is looking good, but with "Page not found". I click on the cart button and a blank page pops up. Any suggestions? Should I edit the .htaccess file? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to route everything into magento's install directory. Maybe add something like this to the htaccess file in your document root?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/httpdocs/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /httpdocs/$1 [L]
```

Comment: that did not work. the page is still blank, BUT the favicon is working. I want to laugh about that. "myDomain.com/index.php" comes up blank. "myDomain.com/httpdocs/index.php" still looks good with header, cart, categories, blocks, and "Page not Found".